# How to make the partition bootable? (installing windows 10 without usb)

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

I have created a partition on my hard disk from windows 10 ISO image (using Disks app)
[image]

Now I have somehow to boot from it. How I can add it to BIOS options menu? (ubuntu 20)

Comment: Windows ISOs are not designed to be bootable when used as a disk image, an AFAIK no ISOs (Windows or not) are designed to be bootable when used as a partition image.

Comment: @gronostaj so how do u boot from it for the installation? LOL

Comment: By burning it to a DVD or creating a bootable flash drive using dedicated tools, like the one from Microsoft, Rufus or WoeUSB. It should also be possible to unpack the installation image onto a partition from another Windows installation, I remember there were tools for that for Win7. What you're trying to do is certainly possible, but it's not trivial and I'm not aware of Linux tools that would allow you to do that. Maybe you could use [this bootloader](https://github.com/pbatard/uefi-ntfs), but again, it's not trivial.